# dbWriteTable in RMySQL error in name pasting

Tags: database, r, stocks, rmysql

i have many `data.frames()` that i am trying to send to MySQL database via `RMySQL()`.

```
# Sends data frame to database without a problem
dbWriteTable(con3, name="SPY", value=SPY , append=T)

# stock1 contains a character vector of stock names...
stock1 <- c("SPY.A")
```

But when I try to loop it:

```
i= 1
while(i <= length(stock1)){
# converts "SPY.A" into SPY 
name <- print(paste0(str_sub(stock1, start = 1, end = -3))[i], quote=F) 
# sends data.frame to database
dbWriteTable(con3,paste0(str_sub(stock1, start = 1, end = -3))[i], value=name, append=T)
i <- 1+i
}
```

The following warning is returned & nothing was sent to database

```
In addition: Warning message:
In file(fn, open = "r") :
cannot open file './SPY': No such file or directory
```

However, I believe that the problem is with pasting `value` onto `dbWriteTable()` since writing `dbWriteTable(con3, "SPY", SPY, append=T)` works but `dbWriteTable(con3, "SPY", name, append=T)` will not...

Comment: I can't recreate an example of this on my system, but I have run into similar situations and have used 'eval(name)' instead of just 'name' in an argument and it worked.  Maybe that can help?

Comment: Thanks, @nfmcclure but `eval(name)` that did not work for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using a non-base package for `str_sub` and I'm guessing you get the same behavior with `substr`. Does this succeed?

```
dbWriteTable(con3,  substr( stock1, 1,3) , get(stock1),  append=T)
```